# Store directory tree in sqlite with java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

What is the best way to store a direcory tree (with file/subdirs names) on sqlite database? 
(any java example code would be appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just store and retrieve the entire directory tree listing, you could save it as an XML file. If you want to make the tree structure visible to sqlite so you can select or change pieces of it (e.g., count the number of files), that's a bit more complicated. See my [earlier post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/hierarchical-sql-problem/5291101#5291101), and especially the article that it links to.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the later, are you aware of any java implementation code of the adjacency tree ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any particular package, but if you google "java adjacency list code" there are lots of promising-looking hits.