# MySQL - how to query a tree?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following table:

```
TABLE: category
 - category_id (PK)
 - parent_id (FK)
 - name
```

Given a value for category_id, how do I return the given category_id and all its descendants?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/hierarchical-sql-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a *single* level, you'd do a SELECT on the condition `category_id = id OR parent_id = id` - but with MySQL, you cannot get a complete tree with a single query.

You *can* write a stored procedure to go through all of the intermediate results and pick up sub-children, but that really isn't very neat.

Instead, you can redesign your table. On the MySQL developer site, there is a [nice article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) about how you can store hierarchical data in a table, and provides a design which is much more flexible than simply using a parent_id.

Comment: +1 for linking to that article, I was looking for it and going to post it, myself.