# MySQL Select All Rows Linked By ID In Same Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the fields:

Parent references the primary key ID in the same table (not foreign key).

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | Parent |   Title    |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      0 | Wallpapers |
|  2 |      1 | Nature     |
|  3 |      2 | Trees      |
|  4 |      3 | Leaves     |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I'm trying to select a row and all its parents. For example if I select "Leaves" I want to get "Trees", "Nature", and "Wallpaper" as well since that is the parent path up the hierarchy. Is this possible in one query? At the moment I'm using a loop in ColdFusion to get the next parent each iteration but it's not efficient enough.

Comment: What should be the output if you select Nature??

Comment: Nature should return Wallpapers since Nature's parent is 1 and 1 is Wallpapers. It shouldn't go forward and find all parents of that one record. This is being used for photo albums so think of it as recursive albums inside each other, so if I'm inside album "Nature" the parent album is Wallpapers etc.

Comment: Why does `Leaves` return `Nature` and `Trees`? The parent of `Leaves` is `1`, and that's `Wallpapers`.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Use a `UNION` to combine the query that returns the main row with a query that returns its parent.

Comment: Are you trying to get the parent plus all siblings?

Comment: check [Link](https://bikashshaw.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/employee-id-employee-name-and-manager-id-self-join-sql-query-as-interview-question/)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, you're right leaves should return trees. I've updated it now.

Comment: Since MySQL doesn't support CTE's, you're basically left with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a self join to achieve this:-

```
 SELECT T1.Title AS CHILD, T2.Title AS PARENT
 FROM YOUR_TABLE T1, YOUR_TABLE T2
 WHERE T1.PARENT = T2.ID
 AND T1.Title = 'Leaves'
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, I wrote a function that retrieve all the hierarchy of my route table (infinite depth).

I think that, in this example, **you can see SQL syntax of query you are looking for**. I use same column names except in lowercase.

```
function get_breadcrumb($route_id) {
    
    //access PDO mysql object instance
    global $db;

    // sanitize route ID
    $route_id = intval($route_id);
    
    // query construction
    $q = "SELECT T2.*
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    @r AS parent_id,
                    (SELECT @r := `parent` FROM `route` WHERE id = parent_id) AS `parent`,
                    @l := @l + 1 AS `depth`
                FROM
                    (SELECT @r := $route_id, @l := 0) vars,
                    `route` T3
                WHERE @r <> 0) T1
            JOIN `route` T2
                ON T1.parent_id = T2.id
            ORDER BY T1.`depth` DESC";
    
    // call query in database
    if($res = $db->query($q)) {
        if($res = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if($size = sizeof($res) > 0) { 
                
                // push results in breadcrumb items array
                $breadcrumb['items']  = $res;
                $breadcrumb['levels'] = $size;
                
                // retrieve only titles
                $titles = array_column($res, 'title');

                // construct html result seperated by '>' or '/'
                $breadcrumb['html']['gt'] = implode(' > ', $titles);
                $breadcrumb['html']['sl'] = implode(' / ', $titles);

                // returns all result (added in SESSION too)
                return $_SESSION['app']['breadcrumb'] = $breadcrumb;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // no result for that route ID
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT c.id AS 'ID', c.title AS 'Name'
FROM YourTable c, YourTable p 
WHERE c.id = p.parent AND c.title = 'Leaves'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a UNION to combine the query that returns the main row with another query that returns the parent row.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Title = "Leaves"
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM YourTable AS t1
JOIN YourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent
WHERE t2.Title = "Leaves")
```

Comment: This only returns one parent, not all parents of a record.

Comment: I thought that's what you want: "It shouldn't go forward and find all parents of that one record".

Comment: You want the parent, the grandparent, the great-grandparent, etc.?

Comment: By that I mean if I selected something like Trees I don't want it to get Leaves, just the stuff before it if that makes sense.

Comment: And you said "you're right, leaves should return trees".

Comment: Sorry having read what I've put I've gotten myself confused. Leaves should return trees, nature and wallpapers as they are all parents of each other.

Comment: MySQL can't do recursion like this in SQL, you'll need to use a procedure, either in the calling language or a MySQL Stored Procedure. I'm trying to find similar questions, but I keep finding questions about getting all the children, not getting the parents.

Comment: This is actually easier than finding all the children, because there's only one parent but there can be many children. So it's just one query per level until you reach the root, you don't need to loop at each level.