# Tree Menu Array php

Tags: php, arrays, uinavigationbar

I can not solve this problem

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [menu] => shoes
            [anchor] => Shoes
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [menu] => futsal-shoes
            [anchor] => Futsal Shoes
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [menu] => lamps
            [anchor] => Lamps
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [menu] => desk-lamps
            [anchor] => Desk Lamps
            [parent] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [menu] => floor-lamps
            [anchor] => Floor Lamps
            [parent] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [menu] => swing-arm-lamps
            [anchor] => Swing Arm Lamps
            [parent] => 4
        )

)
```

this function display all array

```
function has_children($rows,$id) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row['parent'] == $id)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function build_menu($rows,$parent=0) {  
    $result = "<ul>";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row['parent'] == $parent) {
            $result .= "<li><a href=\"$row[menu]\">$row[anchor]</a>";
        if (has_children($rows,$row['id']))
            $result.= build_menu($rows,$row['id']);
            $result .= "</li>";
        }
    }
    $result.= "</ul>";
    return $result;
}
echo build_menu($array);
```

I need display only related tree menu from page

if GET category=lamps

or GET subcategory=floor-lamps

or GET sub_subcategory=swing-arm-lamps

they display only related (not all arrays)

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Lamps</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Desk Lamps</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Swing Arm Lamps</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="">Floor Lamps</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method for you. This code goes below your functions. Basically we get a variable from the GET array and assign it to $current_menu. Then we use a foreach to get the id of that particular menu item (this would be simpler if the keys of your array were the ['menu'] items) and assign it to $parent. Finally, we pass $parent into the build_menus function.

```
//A terse way to do it, instead of typing out all those GETs
//NOTE: This assumes you'll only have one of these at a time.
$cats = array("category", "subcategory", "sub_subcategory");
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    if (isset($_GET[$cat])) {
        $current_menu = $_GET[$cat];    
    }
}

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($current_menu == $arr['menu']) {
        $parent = $arr['parent'];   
    }
}

echo build_menu($array, $parent);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer larsAnders, I've tried your code
this work for
GET floor-lamps & GET swing-arm-lamps
but not include lamps

when I try GET lamps, this code display all array
I will try again using this principle

Comment: In your array, the parent of Lamps is set to 0, so it will display the entire array. If you change the parent in the array, it will display less.

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE `thematic_tree` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

PHP:

```
class Thematic {

private $thematics;

public function __construct($database) {

    $this->database = $database;
    $this->thematics = $this->Init();
}

private function Init() {
    $result = [];
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM thematic_tree;"; 
    if ($res = $this->database->query($SQL) ) {
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) $result[] = $row;
        $res->close();
    }
    return $result;
}

private function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['id']])){
            $l['childs'] = $this->createTree($list, $list[$l['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    }
    return $tree;
}

public function getTree(){
    $new = array();
    foreach ($this->thematics as $a){
        $new[$a['parent_id']][] = $a;
    }
    return $this->createTree($new, $new[0]);
}
```

TWIG:

```
        {% macro menu_links(thematics, base_path) %}
        {% for item in thematics %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ base_path }}/thematic/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
                {% if item.childs %}
                    <ul>
                        {{ _self.menu_links(item.childs, base_path) }}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% import _self as macros %}
    <ul class="main-menu">
        {{ macros.menu_links(thematics, base_path) }}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit verbose, nevertheless:

```
<?php

$flat = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0, 'menu' => 'shoes', 'anchor' => 'Shoes'),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent' => 1, 'menu' => 'futsal-shoes', 'anchor' => 'Futsal Shoes'),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent' => 0, 'menu' => 'lamps', 'anchor' => 'Lamps'),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 3, 'menu' => 'desk-lamps', 'anchor' => 'Desk Lamps'),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 3, 'menu' => 'floor-lamps', 'anchor' => 'Floor Lamps'),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 4, 'menu' => 'swing-arm-lamps', 'anchor' => 'Swing Arm Lamps'),
);

$root = array(
    'children' => array_tree_expand($flat, 'id', 'parent')
);

$query = array('menu' => 'shoes');

if (empty($query)) {
    build_menu_children($root['children']);
}
else {
    $item = array_tree_find($root, array('menu' => 'shoes'));
    if ($item) {
        build_menu($item);
    }
    else {
        echo 'error: not found';
    }
}
echo "\n";

function build_menu($root)
{
    echo '<ul><li>';
    echo sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', htmlspecialchars($root['menu']), htmlspecialchars($root['anchor']));
    if ($root['children']) {
        build_menu_children($root['children']);
    }
    echo '</li></ul>';
}

function build_menu_children(array $children)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', htmlspecialchars($child['menu']), htmlspecialchars($child['anchor']));
        if (count($child['children'])) {
            build_menu_children($child['children']);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function array_tree_find(array $root, array $query)
{
    $match = true;
    foreach ($query as $k => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($k, $root)) {
            $match = false;
            break;
        }
        if ($root[$k] !== $query[$k]) {
            $match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($match) {
        return $root;
    }

    foreach ($root['children'] as $child) {
        $found = array_tree_find($child, $query);
        if ($found !== null) {
            return $found;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/25478474
function array_tree_expand(array $array, $id = 'id', $parent = 'pid', $children = 'children')
{
    $r = array();
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        $k = $v[$id];
        $r[$k] = $v;
        $r[$k][$children] = array();
    }
    $adopted = array();
    foreach ($r as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($r[$v[$parent]])) {
            $r[$v[$parent]][$children][] = &$r[$k];
            $adopted[] = $k;
        }
    }
    foreach ($adopted as $id) {
        unset($r[$id]);
    }
    return $r;
}

function array_tree_flatten(array $tree, $children = 'children', $level = 'level')
{
    $spec = compact('children', 'level');
    $ret = array();
    array_tree_flatten_walk($ret, $tree, $spec);
    return $ret;
}

function array_tree_flatten_walk(array &$ret, array $tree, array $spec, $level = 0)
{
    foreach ($tree as $child) {
        $children = $child[$spec['children']];
        unset($child[$spec['children']]);
        $child[$spec['level']] = $level;
        $ret[] = $child;
        array_tree_flatten_walk($ret, $children, $spec, $level + 1);
    }
}
```

You can save in into `a.php` and the run `php a.php`.