# Merging flat array with itself to build a multidimensional array recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

**Trying to get a multidimensional array from my flat data**

### available raw data

This raw data ist available to me. I need to build a multidimensional array where all children are stored within their respective parents.

```
Array
(
    [index] => Array
    (
        [slug] => index
        [parent_slug] => 
    )
    [praxis-und-team] => Array
    (
        [slug] => praxis-und-team
        [parent_slug] => 
    )
    [leistungen] => Array
    (
        [slug] => leistungen
        [parent_slug] => praxis-und-team
    )
    [partner-und-netzwerk] => Array
    (
        [slug] => partner-und-netzwerk
        [parent_slug] => 
    )
    [notfall] => Array
    (
        [slug] => notfall
        [parent_slug] => 
    )
    [impressum] => Array
    (
        [slug] => impressum
        [parent_slug] => leistungen
    )
)
```

### needed data

It's all about the slug/parent_slug pairing. **There might be more sublevels**, so it has to be recursive until `parent_slug == ''` is reached at the topmost level. This is what the **output** should look like:

```
Array
(
    [index] => Array
    (
        [slug] => index
        [parent_slug] => 
    )
    [praxis-und-team] => Array
    (
        [slug] => praxis-und-team
        [parent_slug] => 
        [children] => Array
        (
            [leistungen] => Array
            (
                [slug] => leistungen
                [parent_slug] => praxis-und-team
                [children] => Array
                (
                    [impressum] => Array
                    (
                        [slug] => impressum
                        [parent_slug] => leistungen
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [partner-und-netzwerk] => Array
    (
        [slug] => partner-und-netzwerk
        [parent_slug] => 
    )
    [notfall] => Array
    (
        [slug] => notfall
        [parent_slug] => 
    )
)
```

*Thank you very much in advance for your help! Sorry if I failed to make light of the problem. I‘ve been looking at it for to long already …*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429487/1192296) and ever so slightly adapted it to my data:

```
function buildTree(array &$elements, $parentId = '')
{
    $branch = array();
    foreach($elements as &$element) {
        if ($element['parent_slug'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['slug']);
            if ($children)
                $element['children'] = $children;
            $branch[$element['slug']] = $element;
            unset($element);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: The entries in the array are from the outermost to the innermost. Thus we could revert the original array, walk thru it **in one pass**, restructure it, and revert it again (if necessary).

### Code

```
    <?php
    $myarray = array(
        'index' => array(
            'slug' => 'index',
            'parent_slug' => '',
        ),
        'praxis-und-team' => array (
            'slug' => 'praxis-und-team',
            'parent_slug' => '',
        ),
        'leistungen' => array(
            'slug' => 'leistungen',
            'parent_slug' => 'praxis-und-team',
        ),
        'partner-und-netzwerk' => array (
            'slug' => 'partner-und-netzwerk',
            'parent_slug' => '',
        ),
        'notfall' => array(
            'slug' => 'notfall',
            'parent_slug' => '',
        ),
        'impressum' => array (
            'slug' => 'impressum',
            'parent_slug' => 'leistungen',
        ),
    );

    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($myarray); echo '</pre>';

    // We want to work from bottom to top
    $myarray = array_reverse($myarray, true);

    foreach($myarray as $key => $item) {
        if (!empty($myarray[$key]['parent_slug'])) {
            $myarray[$myarray[$key]['parent_slug']]['children'][$key] = $myarray[$key];
            unset($myarray[$key]);
        }
    }

    // Now reverse the array again.
    $myarray = array_reverse($myarray, true);

    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($myarray); echo '</pre>';


    ?>
```

### Output

```
    array(4) {
      ["index"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["slug"]=>string(5) "index"
        ["parent_slug"]=>string(0) ""
      }
      ["praxis-und-team"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["slug"]=>string(15) "praxis-und-team"
        ["parent_slug"]=>string(0) ""
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["leistungen"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["slug"]=>string(10) "leistungen"
            ["parent_slug"]=>string(15) "praxis-und-team"
            ["children"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["impressum"]=>
              array(2) {
                ["slug"]=>string(9) "impressum"
                ["parent_slug"]=>string(10) "leistungen"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ["partner-und-netzwerk"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["slug"]=>string(20) "partner-und-netzwerk"
        ["parent_slug"]=>string(0) ""
      }
      ["notfall"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["slug"]=>string(7) "notfall"
        ["parent_slug"]=>string(0) ""
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Trying it now.