# LEFT JOIN into nested array in php

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Im looking for a general solution for such queries:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.FK_ID
SELECT * FROM A

LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.FK_ID
LEFT JOIN C on B.ID = C.FK_ID
```

to have it in an array, so joined records would be in a nested arrays. It's very complicated isn't it? All I have is the query and fetched all records

EDIT:

it normally would return

```
A.col1  A.col2  A.col3  B.col1  B.col2  B.col3
```

if A has 4 rows and 2 records of B connects to A, A will have 5 lines. Instead, I want this:

```
A.col1  A.col2  A.col3  B (array)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your question? What is a "joined record"? How do you decide which columns returned by your query are nested and to what depth? There is one column which exists in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct the source array slightly different you can use this function.

It's a duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431463/more-efficient-hierarchy-system/8431551) (parent_id,id,title):

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM categories");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
  $names[$r[0]] = $r[2];
  $children[$r[0]][] = $r[1];
 }

function render_select($root=0, $level=-1) {
  global $names, $children;
  if ($root != 0)
    echo '<option>' . strrep(' ', $level) . $names[$root] . '</option>';
  foreach ($children[$root] as $child)
    render_select($child, $level+1);
}

echo '<select>';
render_select();
echo '</select>';
```