# Undefined Offset 0 , how can i set this array

Tags: php, sql, undefined, offset

Hello i have an Undefined Offset 0 . inside this code.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
if (false === $q) {
    echo mysql_error();
}

while ($r = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
  $names[$r[0]] = $r[2];
  $children[$r[0]][] = $r[1];
}

function render_select($root=0, $level=-1) {
  global $names, $children;
  if ($root != 0)
    echo '<option>' . strrep(' ', $level) . $names[$root] . '</option>';
  foreach ($children[$root] as $child)
    render_select($child, $level+1);
}

echo '<select>';
render_select();
echo '</select>';
```

The exact line where the error is :

```
foreach ($children[$root] as $child)
    render_select($child, $level+1);
```

This is for a selectbox with a tree format, i found this code in this question

[More efficient hierarchy system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431463/more-efficient-hierarchy-system/8431551)

Answer (score 1):

There is some ambiguity in your code here:

```
if ($root != 0)
    echo '<option>' . strrep(' ', $level) . $names[$root] . '</option>';
  foreach ($children[$root] as $child)
    render_select($child, $level+1);
```

If you are attempting to execute these three lines only if `$root != 0`, you will need to add curly braces like this:

```
if ($root != 0)
{
    echo '<option>' . strrep(' ', $level) . $names[$root] . '</option>';
    foreach ($children[$root] as $child)
    {
        render_select($child, $level+1);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, anytime `render_select` is called without a parameter (or with a first parameter value of '0') you will attempt to access the element of $children at array key '0'. As your error indicates, $children does not contain a value at that key.

Comment: Thanks very much , indeed thats a big mistake, anyway, the error dissapear but my select box is empty :(.. snif

Comment: @DreaminMediaQueretaro  It will remain empty as long as $root = 0, because the loop that creates the `<option>` tags never executes. You will have to determine that circumstances would cause `$root` to be something other than '0'.

Comment: Ok, i try to do it with $root = 1 just for test, i cant get the loop work just get the category with id=1, so i guess the answer from where i copy the code... requiers more customization of what he says, anyway, its above my recent learning, is there a simple, easier, maybe larger (write more).... understandable (easy) code to build a selectbox tree for (id, parent_id, name) estructure. thanks