# How to transform a MSSQL CTE query to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, common-table-expression, adjacency-list

in my MySQL schema, I have the `category(id, parentid, name)` table

In the MSSQL, I have that CTE query (to build a category tree from the bottom up for a supplied category ID:

```
with CTE (id, pid, name) 
as
(
    select id, parentid as pid,name
    from category
    where id = 197
      union all
        select CTE.pid as id , category.parentid as pid, category.name
        from CTE 
          inner join category 
            on category.id = CTE.pid
 )
 select * from CTE
```

How to 'transform' that query to MySQL ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support CTE (Common Table Expressions). This is long overdue IMO. Often, you can just use a subquery instead, but this particular CTE is *recursive*: it refers to itself inside the query. Recursive CTE's are extremely useful for hierarchical data, but again: MySql doesn't support them at all. You have to implement a stored procedure to get the same results.

A previous answer of mine should provide a good starting point:

> [Generating Depth based tree from Hierarchical Data in MySQL (no CTEs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/hierarchical-sql-problem/5291159#5291159)

Comment: @f00, so are they ever going to implement it? Or is the answer "never"?

Answer (score 4):

Thankfully it's not necessary anymore, as MySQL starting from [8.0.1](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/8.0.html) [supports CTE](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16938206)

Comment: @Jonathan But it does answer the question :)

Comment: @KubaOber You're right - I probably should have marked it has link-only answer instead.  You should really add some code to explain how this works rather than just linking to a website.  This way it's less likely to get flagged and down-voted.  Once you have done that, leave a comment and I will retract my comment.

Comment: In fact I expect it should now work "as is". If there some other problems in run that query on MySQL then question should be clarified with details.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately MYSQl or XAMPP(MARIADB) mysql doesnot support CTEs(COMMON TABLE EXPRESSIONS),
for the same you will have to use nested queries.

for more information click on the below link:-

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/

Comment: Please include essential information from the linked site in your answer - links are not so dependable.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what version of MySQL you have using `SELECT VERSION();`
If it is 8 or above you can then proceed further with my comment.
With MySQL 8.0, MariaDB 10.2, and later versions, you can use recursive CTEs:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE (id, pid, name) AS (
    select id, parentid as pid,name
from category
where id = 197
  union all
    select CTE.pid as id , category.parentid as pid, category.name
    from CTE 
      inner join category 
        on category.id = CTE.pid
)
select * from CTE ;
```

Note that CTEs are limited by cte_max_recursion_depth (default 1000, max 4,294,967,295 (2³²−1)) in MySQL and by max_recursive_iterations (default 4,294,967,295) in MariaDB.

You can increase the limit by executing:

```
SET cte_max_recursion_depth = 4294967295;
```

It will only affect your current session and won't be persisted.