# Composite key queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a table called Modules with columns (M_Id, Name, Version, Descr). I have another table detailing dependencies for each modules, i.e. a module may be dependent upon another. For this I use a table called Mod_depends which has the composite key (M_Id_1, Depends).
Example entries:

```
Module
1 | Chameleon | 2.9.2 | HTML/XML template engine
2 | Unittest2 | 1.0.0 | unittest module
3 | OrderedDict | 1.0.1 | Ordered dictionary

Mod_depends
1 | 2
1 | 3
```

I'm looking for a MySQL query that, for a given id, can return entries from the Modules table representing the dependencies. In the example above, supplying Id = 1 would return:

```
2 | Unittest2 | 1.0.0 | unittest module
3 | OrderedDict | 1.0.1 | Ordered dictionary
```

Does this require a join or some subquery magic or both?

Is there a way I can add constraints such that additions to the Mod_depends table is only possible when an entry exists in then Modules table?

Cheers

Cheers

Comment: Does it have to return the second-, third- and so on order dependencies? For example, if module 2 is in turn dependent on module 4, should query for module 1 return module 4 as its dependency as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest case (first-order dependencies only) it's something like this:

```
    SELECT m.M_id, m.Name, m.Version, m.Descr
      FROM Module AS m
INNER JOIN Mod_depends AS md
        ON m.M_id = md.Depends
     WHERE md.M_Id_1 = 1;
```

... but it'd be a really non-trivial task to find more deep dependencies, as it'll become a query for tree-like structure. So you can either use [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999888/mysql-adjacency-list-model-get-depth) for ideas, or reorganize your DB from Adjacency List to Closure Table. Perhaps you'd want to check [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/1229023) as well. )

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't give the names of your fields, so I just made some up that should hopefully be explanatory. Basically you join on the id in teh module table and the dependency id (right column) in the mod_depends table, then lookup using the module id (left column) in the mod_depends table like this:

```
SELECT m.module_id, m.module_name, m.module_version, m.module_description FROM module as m INNER JOIN mod_depends as md on m.module_id = md.module_dependency_id
WHERE md.module_id = 1;
```