# MySQL Return query result if condition is met, without repeating query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Let's say I have something as basic as

```
SELECT IF( (1 + 2) >=0, (1 + 2), 0)
FROM DUAL
```

which will obviously return 3.

Is there a way to NOT repeat the query I want to return (here 1 + 2)?

To put in context, I want to return the number of tasks remaining to do for the current month (at least 4 must be done), but if more than 4 are already done, there is no need to do more so I want to return 0.

What I have done is

```
IF((4 - IFNULL((LONG QUERY RETURNING THE NUMBER OF TASKS DONE THIS MONTH FOR A PARTICULAR USER ),0)) >= 0,
(4 - IFNULL((LONG QUERY RETURNING THE NUMBER OF TASKS DONE THIS MONTH FOR A PARTICULAR USER ), 
0)
```

But is there a way to not repeat the query since it is long and I don't want the server to execute the same query twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending your request, you might want to use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT 1+2 INTO @tmp;
SELECT IF( @tmp >=0, @tmp, 0)
```

Or if you like *one liners*

```
SELECT IF( (@tmp := (1+2)) >=0, @tmp, 0)
--         ^             ^
--        don't forget those parenthesis !
```

---

**EDIT:** This works for "table select" statements too:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl AS SELECT 1 as a UNION SELECT 2;
SELECT SUM(a) FROM tbl INTO @tmp;
SELECT IF ( @tmp > 0, @tmp, 0);
```

If you look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37c33/1 for the *execution plan* of the above queries, you will see the second `SELECT` don't use the table.

---

BTW, please note that with your actual example, this could have been written:

```
SELECT MAX( (1+2), 0 )
--          ^^^^^ here your expression
```

... but I think this is *not* a property of your *real* query?

Comment: The thing is that this is part of a bigger query. It's one of the _select_expr_ of the SELECT statement. I don't think it would be possible...

Comment: @JPP. You will probably have to show an example of *actual* query. But as far as I can tell, [according to the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), *select_expr* is allowed in `SELECT ... INTO`

Comment: -Neverming the first comment, I did'nt see your edit at time of writing - I didn't think of doing `MAX()` but now that you said it, it would actually work. But the method I should really use is the _one liner_ you proposed. I did't know I could do that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
SELECT IF( (@a:=(1 + 2)) >=0, @a, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

**One statement solution**

A way to solve this problem in MySQL is to save the output of the heavy query and reuse multiple times. Take a look here:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN @Value - 4 > 0 
  THEN @Value ELSE 0 
  END
FROM (SELECT @Value := (SELECT 1)) Query
```

where «SELECT 1» should be replaced by your query.

**OT**

Another way to perform your query would require the support of CTE (Common Table Expression).

For what I know this feature is missing in MySQL ([How to transform a MSSQL CTE query to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833535/how-to-transform-a-mssql-cte-query-to-mysql))

Just to give you a taste of its expressiveness in MSSQL, where CTE is available, you could write something like that:

```
with Query (value) 
as
(
    select 1
 )
select 
  case
    when (select value from Query) - 4 > 0
      then (select value from Query)
    else
      0
  end
```

Indeed CTE are more powerful especially when dealing with recursive relations.