# Updating column amount

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this table schema and data,I have no idea on how can I update all parentid 7,5 and 1 if there is new member added under parentid 7 example the newly added is 10.Then all his parentsid go up in the tree (**Note:** up to 10 parents only starting parentid 7 to go up in the tree can be updated there amount) 7,5 and 1 will be added amount to 500.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytree` (
    `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `memd` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `position` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `amount` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;



pid          memd     position      amount

0             1                     1000.00

1             5          L          500.00

1             6          R          0.00

5             7          L          0.00

5             8          R          0.00

7             9          L          0.00
```

Here is my tree.

[image]

After added new member 10

```
pid          memd     position      amount

0             1                     1500.00

1             5          L          1000.00

1             6          R          0.00

5             7          L          500.00

5             8          R          0.00

7             9          L          0.00

7             10         R          0.00
```

**EDIT**
IF the parent has no child yet then added a new one,the parent cannot recieve 500,or there is no update could be made in amount of parent.

**EDIT latest problem**

Problem if I have series of one child,then one of the children get paired.,it will only update the amount of his direct parent,the above parent of his parent etc.., did not updated, how can I update those his parent even it has only 1 child,example 9 and 10 should receive also amount because they are the parent of **'11'**

```
   pid          memd     position      amount

    0             1                     1500.00

    1             5          L          1000.00

    1             6          R          0.00

    5             7          L          500.00

    5             8          R          0.00

    7             9          L          0.00

    9             10         L          0.00

    10             11         L          0.00

    11             12         L          0.00

    11             13         R          0.00
```

How can I achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tell me what will happend if i add 11 as child of 7 ??

Comment: @smn_onrocks,thank you for the reply..It is controlled in registration form before the admin will add 11(new member) he will check first if that member 7 has no left or right child,if already have, then admin will assign parent for the new member which has no child yet.

Comment: and what about the amount?? I mean when amount is added your amount updation logic is not very clear for me.

Comment: @smn_onrocks,okay I'll try to explain, when 11 is added in parent 9,since parent 9 has no child yet there is no update could be made.,..this is the requirment if any of the donwlines get paired then his parent will receive 500 go up to the tree (only 10 parent) beyond that 10 parents they cannot receive 500.

Comment: @smn_onrocks,did i explain well ?

Comment: I think in that case better you write a store proc for implementing the business logic .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model read the details. you will get the idea how to maintain this kind of model.

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul I already read that it's difficult to implement in my registration form I could not let the member put the position left or riht because it bases on link nodes

Comment: @smn_onrocks,I have no idea on creating sp.that's also my problem

Comment: @smn_onrocks, do you have any reference on sp that suited to my problem?

Comment: I will try to solve your scenario but not sure please provide the input parameters you want to pass.

Comment: the parameter is the memberid because this is what i used in my registration form if i add new member,just put example memberid 10 (a new meberid) added under parent 7..so 7 will receive 500, parent 5 will receive 500(1000) and parent 1 will receive 500 (1500).thank you in advance.

Comment: @smn_onrocks,can you please not to limit 10 parents go up to tree,just update the amount whoever his parents.so that this could be easy for you.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you plese let me know was it help ful or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted

```
create procedure sp_update_amt(IN p_mem  INT)
BEGIN
    declare cnt INT;
    declare par_id INT;
    declare cntr INT;
    declare m_mem INT;
    declare s_str VARCHAR(512);
    set cntr=1;
    set par_id = 1;
    set m_mem = p_mem;
    set s_str = '';
proc_label:BEGIN
    WHILE par_id != 0 DO
      SELECT pid INTO par_id FROM mytree WHERE memd=m_mem;
      select count(*) into cnt FROM mytree WHERE pid=par_id;
      set s_str = CONCAT(s_str,cnt,cntr,par_id,m_mem,',');      
      set cntr = cntr+1;
      set m_mem = par_id;
        IF cntr <=10 THEN
          update mytree set amount = amount+500 
          where memd=par_id;
        ELSE
          update mytree set amount = amount+200 
          where memd=par_id;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
end;
    SELECT s_str;
END;
```

Try the above code think this will work and solve your problem 
for details check the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/788b1/1)

**EDIT AND UPDATED CODE**

I think this WOULD solve your requirement.

```
create procedure sp_update_amt(IN p_mem  INT)
BEGIN
    declare cnt INT;
    declare par_id INT;
    declare cntr INT;
    declare m_mem INT;
    declare s_str VARCHAR(512);
    set cntr=1;
    set par_id = 1;
    set m_mem = p_mem;
    set s_str = '';
proc_label:BEGIN
    WHILE par_id != 0 DO
      SELECT pid INTO par_id FROM mytree WHERE memd=m_mem;
      select count(*) into cnt FROM mytree WHERE pid=par_id;
      set s_str = CONCAT(s_str,cnt,cntr,par_id,m_mem,',');      
      set m_mem = par_id;
      IF cnt = 2 OR cntr > 1 THEN
        IF cntr <= 10 THEN
          update mytree set amount = amount +500 
          where memd=par_id;
        ELSE
          update mytree set amount = amount+200 
          where memd=par_id;
        END IF;
      ELSE
        LEAVE proc_label;
      END IF;
      set cntr = cntr+1;
    END WHILE;
end;
    SELECT s_str;
END;
```

Check the link for your data and code [updated](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03d96/1)

Comment: thank you for the reply...why is it that it will add immediately the amount?

Comment: First let me know is it working or not giving a up vote as u have accepted the ans so any one facing the same problem could consider the ans then i will explain it

Comment: ,...okay I give you my vote now :)...i tried to reset my table and initial 1 as the root.when I add 2 as a child of 1 it update the amount of 1,but it should not update yet because 1 has only one child he did not get paired yet.

Comment: your last post on dec 24,that works fine to me but there is a little problem...here is the scenario.I tried 1 as root then 2 as child of 1,then 3 as child of 1,the amount of 1 is updated it's okay.now I add 4 as child of 2 then add 5 as child of 4 then 6 as child of 5 then 7 as child of 6 then 8 as child of 7 then 9 as child of 7,parent 7 get paired the amount was updated,but what about 6,5 and 4 they are the parent of 7 they should get updated.but the sp only update the 7 amount.this was the problem in your last post dec 24.thank you in advance.and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: ,how can i give that bounty to you from jemz?

Comment: I vote again in your post,the answere that i accepted before,i don't know why it remove.

Comment: Please take the second sp as the final one hope this will solve the problem .and let me know dose that solve or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68341/discussion-between-ashton-and-smn-onrocks).

Answer (score 2):

Here Is your code

```
create procedure sp_update_amt(IN p_mem  INT)
BEGIN
    declare cnt INT;
    declare par_id INT;
    declare cntr INT;
    declare m_mem INT;
    set cntr=1;
    set par_id = 1;
    set m_mem = p_mem;
    set s_str = '';
proc_label:BEGIN
    WHILE cntr <= 10 and par_id != 0 DO
      SELECT pid INTO par_id FROM mytree WHERE memd=m_mem;
      select count(*) into cnt FROM mytree WHERE pid=par_id;           
      set cntr = cntr+1;
      set m_mem = par_id;
      IF cnt = 2 THEN
        update mytree set amount = amount+500 
        where memd=par_id;
      ELSE
        LEAVE proc_label;
      END IF;
    END WHILE;
end;

END;
```

After `inserting` a `row` call the `sp_update_amt` by `call sp_update_amt(inserted_memberid);`
that will work.
you can chake the entire thing on this [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c52f6/2)

**EDITED current VERSION**

```
create procedure sp_update_amt(IN p_mem  INT)
BEGIN
    declare cnt INT;
    declare par_id INT;
    declare cntr INT;
    declare m_mem INT;
    declare s_str VARCHAR(512);
    set cntr=1;
    set par_id = 1;
    set m_mem = p_mem;
    set s_str = '';
proc_label:BEGIN
    WHILE par_id != 0 DO
      SELECT pid INTO par_id FROM mytree WHERE memd=m_mem;
      select count(*) into cnt FROM mytree WHERE pid=par_id;
      set s_str = CONCAT(s_str,cnt,cntr,par_id,m_mem,',');      
      set cntr = cntr+1;
      set m_mem = par_id;
      IF cnt = 2 THEN
        IF cntr <=10 THEN
          update mytree set amount = amount+500 
          where memd=par_id;
        ELSE
          update mytree set amount = amount+200 
          where memd=par_id;
        END IF;
      ELSE
        LEAVE proc_label;
      END IF;
    END WHILE;
end;
    SELECT s_str;
END;
```

Comment: ,It works I tested it thank you so much for helping me,can I ask how did you come up this solution if you don't mind.Thank you in advance

Comment: c my logic was clear what i need  to do and belive me this is my first in mysql i never tried this data base before.

Comment: that cntr <=10 is that for parents for updating 10 parentid go to top tree ?

Comment: ,can I ask can I remove cntr<=10 in the while loop,if ever they change there mind to just update all his parentid to give 500 ?

Comment: Yes that can be done and the `cntr <=10` is just to restrict the updation in parent level up to 10 levels

Comment: ,is it possible if those parents are above 10 level,I will give them 200 amounts.?thank you in advance

Comment: @ashTon yes why not. it is possible you have to modify the code acordingly

Comment: I edit my post,I change now the code accordingly but can you please help me if that is the correct way.thank you in advance.

Comment: @ashTon I have upload the updated code please use that one and let me know how it works

Comment: ,it works I tested it,I will write you back if I have problem  thank you so much again.

Comment: I have problem,if I will add 11 under 9 (left) as child then add 12 under 11(left) as child then add  13 and 14 child  under 12,it will only update the 12 amount and the sp will not continue to update .please help me.thank you in advance

Comment: ,..I post my latest problem please see my updated problem.I really need your help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I will be out for few days if you find any problem please mail me on subhankarmitraneogi@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this with a recursive common table expression, but mysql does not support them.  Therefore just write a stored procedure to do this.

Here is a link to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833676/4350148