# inner join select statements on itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement that is built out of two select statements that are inner joined

```
SELECT stuff FROM
    (multiple SELECT statements) AS T1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT stuff FROM
        (multiple SELECT statements same as T1)) AS T2 ON more stuff
```

What I did was copy paste T1 select statement, is there a way to give T1 a name that can be recognized in the sub query creating T2?
PS Im using MySQL

Comment: Not in MySQL, unless you are able to use a view.  Other databases support CTEs.  However, perhaps the subquery is not needed.

Comment: MySQL goes out of its way to make this difficult. It doesn't have CTEs, and it also doesn't allow you to use a temporary table multiple times in a query. You have to define a view or copy the result of the query to a regular table.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting 'WITH CTE' MSSQL to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113076/converting-with-cte-mssql-to-mysql)