# Mysql query to retrieve child and parent data from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table as in below figure.

[image]

Now i want to query to this table so that i get data as follows

[image]

If there is no parent then parent must be populated as "NONE" or Empty. How do i achieve this query? Is this even possible? I discussed this with my friend but still no answer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join your table with itself, using a LEFT JOIN that will return all rows from the left table and the rows from the second table that match the join condition:

```
Select
  t1.ID,
  t1.Name,
  t2.Name AS Parent,
  t1.Remarks
From
  yourtable t1 LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
  ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
```

you could also use `COALESCE(t2.name, 'NONE') AS Parent` to return the string NONE when there's no match.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server, you can use `CTE (Common Table Expression)` - hierarchical query to retrieve child and leaf level childs. But my sql does not support CTE.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833535/how-to-transform-a-mssql-cte-query-to-mysql) question which represents that MySQL does not support CTE.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159) will help you to get all the child and child of that child. You need to create hierarchical query.