# mysql query for alternatives

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**Part**: id, partnumber
**Alternative**: partid, alternativepartid

Let's say that **Part** contains the following records:

- 1 - part 1 2
- 2 - part 2
- 3 - part 3
- 4 - part 4
- 5 - part 5

And **Alternative** contains the following records:

- 1 - 2
- 1 - 3
- 2 - 4
- 3 - 5

I would like to create a query to get all parts that are related to a given id.

In my case that would mean that if I query for part 1 (id 1) I would like to find:

2 and 3 but also 4 and 5 as 4 is an alternative to 2 and 5 is an alternative to 3.

When I query for 3, I would like to find: 5, 1, 2, and 4

Does this make sense?

Would it be possible to retrieve the complete set of records in one query?

Thanks!

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159) is similar to what you want.

Comment: This would have been possible with Common Table Expressions in SQLServer, but MySQL doesn't support them. So, you may have to use a stored procedure for this.

Comment: Just a suggestion but you could try to do this with a set of SQL Rules that follow these product chains before they return results.

Comment: Question: How many levels deep does this chaining go?

Comment: It could be infinite I guess as one alternative may point to any other alternative.