# SQL: Retrieving total sum as subselect very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, sum, subquery

I am trying to fetch some averages and some sums over several rows, grouping by each hour of the day. Plus I want to fetch an additional column, where I don't get the sums for each hour (which is fetched when grouping), but where I want to fetch the total sum over all rows until that specific date. The SQL-statement is posted below.

My problem is now, that executing the query on a MySQL database over ~25k rows takes about 8 seconds (CPU i5/8GB RAM). I identified that the subselect (`... AS 'rain_sum'`) makes it very slow. My question is now: Do I think in a too complex way? Is there an easier way to get the same results I get from the query below?

```
SELECT
    `timestamp_local` AS `date`,
    AVG(`one`) AS `one_avg`,
    AVG(`two`) AS `two_avg`,
    SUM(`three`) AS `three_sum`,
    (SELECT SUM(`b`.`three`)
        FROM `table` AS `b`
        WHERE `b`.`timestamp_local` <= SUBDATE(`a`.`timestamp_local`, INTERVAL -1 SECOND)
        LIMIT 0,1) AS `three_sum`
FROM  `table` AS  `a`
GROUP BY
    HOUR( `a`.`timestamp_local` ),
    DAY( `a`.`timestamp_local` ),
    MONTH( `a`.`timestamp_local` ),
    WEEK( `a`.`timestamp_local` ),
    YEAR( `a`.`timestamp_local` )
ORDER BY `a`.`timestamp_local` DESC
LIMIT 0, 24;
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` please.  Mainly, do you have an index on `timestamp_local`?

Comment: Yes, there is an index on `timestamp_local`. What do you mean by `SHOW CREATE TABLE`? Do you want to know the structure of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than grouping on all those fields, a simpler (and faster) solution (from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Funix-timestamp)) may be:

```
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_local)/3600
```

I can't imagine that your query returns the results you want (if I understand your requirements correctly). I understand your requirements as, when there are no rows for a given hour, you want to calculate the sum of all rows with hour < that hour. MySQL won't select empty groupings (for the sub-query part).

There's no easy efficient way to do this in MySQL that I know of, I would suggest creating a temporary table with all possible grouping values in the range that your looking at (probably with a loop). You can probably set this table up beforehand for a few years, and possibly add rows as required. Then you can just left join this table and your table.

If you were using MSSQL, you could've used a recursive CTE, though this would probably have been very slow. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes) or google "mysql cte" for MySQL alternatives. The way to do this with recursion is to (left) join on the same table repeatedly for `HOUR = HOUR+1` until you get a non-NULL value, then stop. For each of these you will calculate the sum backwards.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I want to fetch the grouped sum for each hour (database contains weather information and I want to fetch the rain amount for each hour, for which I use the regular `SUM()`). But beside the rain amount for each hour I also want to fetch the total amount of rain that has occured since the database has been filled with weather information (e.g. 5mm rain amount last hour, 550mm rain amount in total since weather recording). But the hint with grouping by timestamp/3600 is awesome and helps. Thanks!

Comment: Most of my answer holds if you want to fetch total rain since the beginning in addition to the rain for this hour, rather than an either / or case. My answer is based on the assumption that there wasn't rain every hour, if there was, this is a simple case of joining the table with itself (not particularly fast to do though, SQL is not really made for this type of operation, but it's very easy in something like C++ or PHP, maybe an intermediate step where you create a table with hourly sums is the way to go).

Comment: That's utterly interesting as I had an PHP algorithm which cumulated the rain amount. But I wanted to implement it in SQL as I thought it would be more efficient and faster (and in the philosophy of software development make more sense to aggregate it while fetching from the DB instead of fetching and then running algorithms over it). So I think I'll re-use my PHP method.

Comment: You can, of course, have a `WHILE` and a `CURSOR` in SQL and do exactly the same as you would in PHP (execute a query to get the rows ordered by hour and calculate the values as you go), but this will likely still be slower or very close to the speed of the PHP, and that's advanced SQL versus basic PHP.

Comment: I praised your timestamp/3600 too fast. When I first tried it out I just watched the sql-execution time go rapidly down but didn't mention that it doesn't give me the proper result. Now each row contains the regular timestamp from each db-row but the grouped average result. So when a row is written into the DB each 30 seconds and I try to fetch last 24h I get 24 rows with regular timestamps (30 second interval) with one single average value (always the same). So grouping this way neither works nor helps.