# Grouping MYSQL result rows by date

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I want to group results I fetch from a MYSQL database by the hour of a timestamp. The timestamp is stored in the table in the format `2012-12-14 03:19:09`. I use the query

```
SELECT
    HOUR(`timestamp`) AS `hour`,
    AVG(`somevalue`) AS `average`
FROM ...
GROUP BY
    HOUR(`timestamp`),
    DAY(`timestamp`),
    MONTH(`timestamp`),
    WEEK(`timestamp`),
    YEAR(`timestamp`)
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 0, 24;
```

This works, and returns correct rows and values...

```
+------+-------+
| hour | value |
+------+-------+
| 13   | 21.16 | 
| 12   | 21.11 |
| 11   | 20.88 |
| 10   | 20.93 |
|  9   | 20.87 |
|  8   | 20.89 |
| ...  | ...   |
+------+-------+
```

... but is extremely slow (table contains ~90k rows). I was [given the advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14067251/1828051) not to group by each date entity, but to group by `` UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`)/3600 ``. This unfortunately does not lead to the desired result, result looks like this

```
+------+-------+
| hour | value |
+------+-------+
| 13   | 21.20 |
| 13   | 21.20 |
| 13   | 21.20 |
| 13   | 21.20 |
| 13   | 21.20 |
| ...  | ...   |
+------+-------+
```

Is there any way to group them by only one group clause (which will make it faster), but returns correct results?

Comment: Using multiple backticks didn't work here for me (see above). If anyone finds the mistake I'm thankful for correction.

Comment: No attempt to solve this problem *with the current schema* will avoid a full table scan and filesort, so will become very expensive for large tables.  You will need to change your schema so that you can group on an index, for example by storing the `DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')` in another (indexed) column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it use group by date and hour

```
SELECT
    HOUR(`timestamp`) AS `hour`,
    AVG(`somevalue`) AS `average`
FROM ...
GROUP BY
    DATE(`timestamp`),
    HOUR(`timestamp`),
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 0, 24;
```

Comment: Looks promising: was 1.4012 seconds, now 0.9345. Almost one third faster!

Answer (score 0):

1. Index the timestamp-column.
2. Try `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y%m%d%H')`.

Please note that I haven't really tried this myself.

Comment: No performance improvement: 1.5021 instead of 1.4012 seconds (approx. increase of 7%) on my machine.