# How can I find the MAX() of some column in a recursive situation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm have a MySQL 5.1 DB with this table (paraphrasing)...

```
contracts
---------
id
parent_id
end_date
```

So contracts can have parent-child relationships via `parent_id`, and there can be several levels of nesting.

Given some contract with an `id` of let's say **1**, how can I write a query to find the last `end_date` among it and its descendants?

(It would also be great to get the `id`s of the contract(s) with that `end_date`.)

Comment: You can't, as far as I know you need multiple queries.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive CTE's but here is a solution using a stored procedure: [Psuedo CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159)

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll use some sort of caching column or table then, along the lines KeepCalmAndCarryOn suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion in SQL can be difficult to implement - what happens if you get a circular relationship too?

I would consider breaking the relationships out into a separate table which explicitly lists them all.

eg

```
 contact_id     super_id     relationship
 1              10           Parent
 1              20           Grandparent
 10             20           Parent
```

and so on. Its a bit of work to keep them up to date but worth the effort. Its also a simple matter to join a contract to all its parents