# How to show the related tasks list from the table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help. I have table name called "Tasks", below

```
SNO Taskname parentid
---------------------
46  Task-1     0
47  Task-2    46
48  Task-3    47
49  Task-4    46
50  task-5    47
51  task-6    50
```

For example, I am in Task page 48, now we would show the related Tasks no. of 48. So, the output would be `46,47,49,50,51`.

I tried the code below, but it does not work:

```
function getTask($task_id) {                    
    $rs=mysql_query("select task_id,taskname,p_id from task where task_id='".$task_id."'");
    $rs_req=mysql_fetch_array($rs) or die(mysql_error());                    
    $reqt=$rs_req['p_id'];                   
    return $reqt;   
}

$task = getTask($task_id);               
$pid = $task;
$related_tasks = [];                

while ($pid != 0) {                 
    $pid = getTask($pid);
    $relatedTasks[] = $pid;
}

print_r($relatedTasks);
```

Comment: It's basically a recursive query.  This might be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5291054

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases are not meant to deal with recursive queries.

You can do it by selecting the first the row with ID 48 and then recursively check of parentId != 0 and execute another query if so. Something like

```
$task = getTask(48);
$related_tasks = [];
while( $task['parentID'] != 0) {
    $task = getTask( $task['parentId']);
    $relatedTasks[] = $task;
}
```

Take a look at [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query).

Comment: i tried code, but its not works. i have updated the code in Question

Comment: do you get some kind of error ? What happens in general ?