# How to fetch children tree of given parent in B-tree

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have table called `tree`  with `id`, and `parent-id` and data are **b-tree**

```
           1
    2             3
4   5   6      7   8  9
```

etc

all these are store in tree table like

```
1 - null
2 - 1
3 - 1
4 - 2
5 - 2
6 - 2
7 - 3
8 - 3
9 - 3
```

etc

so **please write Query to fetch child tree of 2**

output should be like

```
4 - 2
5 - 2
6 - 2
xx - 4
etc..
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What have you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159

Answer (score 0):

Select id, parent_id from tablename where parent_id = 2. Perhaps you need bottom level ones? Then you need to left join the table with itself and only return the rows that don't have children.

Edit: if the maximum number of hierarchy levels is high or unknown, you should use hierarchyid: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx

Hope this helps!