# Complex SQL Query Self Referential table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a self referential table:

```
ID|NAME|PARENT_ID
1 |P   |NULL
2 |C1  | 1
3 |C2  | 1
4 |C3  | 2
5 |C4  | 4
```

I'm trying to write a query to get all the children of an ID (infinite levels)
For example: 
When input is 1, i want all the rows which are descendants of 1 i.e

```
ID|NAME|PARENT_ID
1 |P   |NULL
2 |C1  | 1
3 |C2  | 1
4 |C3  | 2
5 |C4  | 4
```

When input is 2:

```
ID|NAME|PARENT_ID
4 |C3  | 2
```

Please check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0236f/9).

I have reached here so far:

```
select id as productid,name,@pv:=parent_id 
from products 
join (select @pv:=1)tmp 
where parent_id=@pv
```

But it only gives me two level records, I need infinite levels of records.

Thank you,
Sash

Comment: This is a hierarchical query.  MySQL basically has no support for hierarchical and recursive queries.  Either you need to change your data structure or use recursive stored procedures.  A simple `select` statement cannot do what you want.

Comment: I think in your second example you are missing `5 |C4  | 4`

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159

Comment: Further to Gordon's comment, this is best I've used so far https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model (it looks chaotic at first glance but it's actually extremely simple to use)

Comment: Check this: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following query:

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from products
         order by parent_id, id) base,
        (select @pv := '1') tmp
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74fc16/27) based on the one provided in the question.

The value specified in `@pv := '1'` should be set to the id of the parent you want to select all the descendants of.

This will work also if a parent has multiple children. However, it is required that for each record `parent_id < id`, otherwise the results will not be complete.

Also note that for very large data sets this solution might get slow, as the `find_in_set` operation is not the most ideal way to find a number in a list, certainly not in a list that reaches a size in the same order of magnitude as the number of records returned.

NB: If you want to have the parent node itself also included in the result set, then prefix the following before the above `SQL` with the `id` value of interest in the `where` clause:

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id 
from    products
where   id = '1'
union
...
```

**Alternative 1: CONNECT BY**

Some other databases have a specific syntax for hierarchical look-ups, such as the `CONNECT BY` clause available on Oracle databases. MySql does not offer such a syntax.

**Alternative 2: smarter identifiers**

Things become a lot easier if you would assign `id` values that contain the hierarchical information. For example, in your case this could look like this:

```
ID      | NAME
1       | P   
1-1     | C1  
1-2     | C2  
1-1-1   | C3  
1-1-1-1 | C4
```

Then your select would look like this:

```
select  id,
        name 
from    products
where   id like '1-%'
```

**Alternative 3: Repeated Self-joins**

If you know an upper limit for how deep your hierarchy tree can become, you can use a standard `sql` like this:

```
select      p5.parent_id as parent5_id,
            p4.parent_id as parent4_id,
            p3.parent_id as parent3_id,
            p2.parent_id as parent2_id,
            p1.parent_id as parent_id,
            p1.id as product_id,
            p1.name
from        products p1
left join   products p2 on p2.id = p1.parent_id 
left join   products p3 on p3.id = p2.parent_id 
left join   products p4 on p4.id = p3.parent_id  
left join   products p5 on p5.id = p4.parent_id  
left join   products p6 on p6.id = p5.parent_id
where       1 in (p1.parent_id, 
                  p2.parent_id, 
                  p3.parent_id, 
                  p4.parent_id, 
                  p5.parent_id) 
order       by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74fc16/29)

The `where` condition specifies which parent you want to retrieve the descendants of. You can extend this query with more levels as needed.

Comment: Hi, i'm using the first query, how can i get the parent category too including the childs?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean that you want the value that you have specified in `@pv := '1'` to be included in a separate column, with a value that will be the same for all records (`1` in this example)?

Comment: No. actually i want the record that you i have specified in @pv := '1'  as a row along with child records

Comment: I added an extension of the query for that purpose in my answer in a new paragraph "NB: ...". It is quite straightforward, just `union` that one record to the result set. By pre-pending it to the base `SQL` you should also get it as the first record in your result set.