# PHP/MYSQL How to generate the child comment under the parent comment when using a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I've tried to work on a stored procedure using the this thread to create a depth-based infinite comment

[Generating Depth based tree from Hierarchical Data in MySQL (no CTEs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes)

And I was able to successfully generate multiple comments, and it's child comments and the child comment's child comment and so on with a single query. My problem is how do I generate the child comment directly under the parent comment?
The query that I've been using

```
CALL comment_procedure('6da6688bad307bb');
```

generated it in order of its depth, I've tried modifying it but I can't seem to generate the right result.

Do I need to edit my stored procedure or do I need a specific PHP code to have the desired output.

```
begin



declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;


create temporary table comment_hier(
 parent_id varchar(50), 
 cmmt_id varchar(50), 
 dateandtime datetime,
 depth smallint unsigned default 0
)engine = memory;

insert into comment_hier select parent_id, cmmt_id , date, v_depth from cmmt_sect where parent_id = c_cmmt_id;

create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from comment_hier;

while not v_done do
if exists( select 1 from cmmt_sect p inner join comment_hier on p.parent_id = comment_hier.cmmt_id and comment_hier.depth = v_depth) then

    insert into comment_hier
        select p.parent_id, p.cmmt_id, date, v_depth + 1 from cmmt_sect p
        inner join tmp on p.parent_id = tmp.cmmt_id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

    set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

    truncate table tmp;
    insert into tmp select * from comment_hier where depth = v_depth;

else
    set v_done = 1;
end if;

end while;

select 
 p.cmmt_id,
 p.content as comment,
 b.cmmt_id as parent_comment_id,
 b.content as parent_comment,
 comment_hier.dateandtime,
 comment_hier.depth
from 
 comment_hier
inner join cmmt_sect p on comment_hier.cmmt_id = p.cmmt_id
left outer join cmmt_sect b on comment_hier.parent_id = b.cmmt_id
order by comment_hier.depth;

drop temporary table if exists comment_hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end
```

Comment: Are you using the EXACT code in the other questions answer?

Comment: No, I'ver changed it a bit, the comment id inserted are randomly generated by php function, also the id are varchar instead on int. But other than that I don't think I've meddled with the code that much.

Comment: Well then you had better show us the code you are really using. Otherwise how in the $%&^ are we supposed to help?

Comment: Added, sorry bout that