# SQL - Recursive Query

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have the following mysql table with sample data as follows:

```
 id    location            parentid
 1     UK                  0
 2     East Anglia         1
 3     Cambridgeshire      2
 4     Norfolk             2
 5     Suffolk             2 
 6     East Midlands       1
 7     Derbyshire          6
 8     Leicestershire      6 
 9     EU Countries        0
 10    Austria             9
 11    Belgium             9
```

I want to generate a query whereby I can get a list of locations  by location name but the location should include any parent location. e.g.

A search for `folk` should return:

```
 id  location
 4   Norfolk, East Anglia, UK
 5   Suffolk, East Anglia, UK
```

A search for `East` should return:

```
id  location
2   East Anglia, UK
6   East Midlands, UK
```

A search for `Bel` should return:

```
id  location
11  Belgium
```

In the above we are excluding concatanting `EU countries`

Obviously the following doesnt work:

```
select c.id, CONCAT_WS(', ', c.location, p.location, pp.location) as location
from tbl_locations c
   outer left join tbl_locations p on p.id = c.parentid
   outer left join tbl_locations pp on pp.id = p.parentid
 where c.location like '%whatever%'
```

Comment: you can make a function that returns the text of given locationid. edit: function must call itself until there is nothing to call(it's also the definition of recursion)

Comment: http://guilhembichot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html

Comment: what is the maximum depth ?

Comment: @sumit, it better does not depend on maximum. it must be recursive, i guess.

Comment: MySQL has no native support for recursion. Options include building a sproc, joining the table to itself as often as could possibly be required, handling the logic in application code, or switching to a different model (see nested sets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want a the parent location this is done with a self join:

```
select c.id, c.location, p.id, p.location
from tbl_locations c
  outer left join tbl_locations p on p.id = c.parentid
where c.location like '%whatever%'
```

This can be extended (via outer joins) to an arbitrary number of levels but the query will get long. Eg. to three levels:

```
select c.id, c.location, p.id, p.location, pp.id, pp.location
from tbl_locations c
  outer left join tbl_locations p on p.id = c.parentid
  outer left join tbl_locations pp on pp.id = p.parentid
where c.location like '%whatever%'
```

More general recursive queries depend on the details of the RDBMS. The easiest approach is to use a Common Table Expression (CTE). But MySQL doesn't support them (at least, not yet). Other approaches can be used: *[Generating Depth based tree from Hierarchical Data in MySQL (no CTEs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5291054/67392)*.

Comment: lets say I have 4 levels, would the above have huge performance implications?

Comment: @adam78: as always depends and you really need to measure with a realistic data set. Even with all UK locations at a detailed level (thousands of rows) and indexed `id` and `parentid` I would expect it to be pretty quick. But the only way to be sure is testing with realistic data, and consider how often you would use such queries.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no standard SQL query which can calculate the "transitive closure" a transitive relation. If you want to nest select statements you will always have a maximum depth that can be reached.

2) There is no standard SQL query which will return a row with a variable number of columns. So you would have to format your results in some way or another (e.g. csv).

However, you can accomplish that in MySQL with a stored procedure:

```
 1 CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
 2 USE test;
 3 
 4 
 5 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS location;
 6 CREATE TABLE location (id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, parent_id INT UNSIGNED NULL REFERENCES location(id));
 7 
 8 INSERT INTO location VALUES
 9 (1,"UK",0), 
10 (2,"East Anglia",1),
11 (3,"Cambridgeshire",2),
12 (4,"Norfolk",2),
13 (5,"Suffolk",2),
14 (6,"East Midlands",1),
15 (7,"Derbyshire",6),
16 (8,"Leicestershire",6);
17 
18 
19 
20 
21 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS location_with_parents;
22 DELIMITER //
23 CREATE FUNCTION location_with_parents(location_id INT UNSIGNED) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) READS SQL DATA
24 BEGIN
25     DECLARE LOC_STR VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
26     DECLARE LOC_ADD VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
27     DECLARE PAR_ID INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT location_id;
28     
29     SELECT name INTO LOC_STR FROM location where id=PAR_ID;
30     loop_label: LOOP 
31         SELECT parent_id INTO PAR_ID FROM location where id=PAR_ID;
32         
33         IF PAR_ID = 0 THEN
34             LEAVE loop_label;
35         ELSE
36             SELECT name INTO LOC_ADD FROM location where id=PAR_ID;
37             SET LOC_STR = CONCAT(LOC_STR, ', ', LOC_ADD); 
38             ITERATE loop_label;
39         END IF;
40     END LOOP loop_label;
41     RETURN LOC_STR;
42     
43 END;
44 //
45 
46 DELIMITER ;
47 
48 
49 
50 SELECT location_with_parents(id) FROM location WHERE name LIKE "%folk%";
51 
52 DROP DATABASE test;
```

Works for me with MySQL 5.6.35

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Below Query gives you exact result which you want using Recursion method.

```
    Select S.ID , 
    concat( S.location,',', Group_concat
    (distinct A.location ORDER BY  A.location  SEPARATOR ',' ) ) as location
    from

         (    SELECT  distinct @r AS _id  ,location,
                        (
                        SELECT  @r := parentid
                        FROM    tbl_locations 
                        WHERE   id = _id
                        ) AS parentid,
                        @l := @l + 1 AS level
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  @r := h.ID,
                                @l := 0,
                                @cl := 0
                         from tbl_locations  h
                         where location like '%folk%'

                        ) vars,
                        tbl_locations  h
                WHERE   @r <> 0


          )A , tbl_locations    S
                where s.location like '%folk%'
                group by S.ID
```

> OutPut :

```
 location like '%East%' :
```

[image]

```
location like '%Folk%'
```

[image]

its good question and check and ask if you have any concerns.