# How to get last child relation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relationship

My table structure:

```
--------------------------
|Categories              |
--------------------------
|id    |parent_id|title  |
--------------------------
|1     |null     |t1     |
--------------------------
|2     |1        |t2     |
--------------------------
|3     |1        |t3     |
--------------------------
|4     |2        |t4     |
--------------------------
|5     |4        |t5     |
--------------------------
|6     |null     |t6     |
--------------------------
```

I need to find out how many items are between a given item/category and its root item/category including the specified item and the root item.

For example in this table `title=t5` would have a count of 4 (`t1`->`t2`->`t4`->`t5`).

MySQL Version: 5.6.21

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @gordon-linoff: 5.6.21

Comment: @AliMohammadi Would you consider update mysql version to support `cte` ?  cte recursion will be easier to make it.

Comment: @D-Shih i cant because on the host server. but can u tell me how can do it by cte?

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql version support `cte` you can try to use *CTE Recursion* make it.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE  Categories(
   id INT,
   parent_id INT,
   title VARCHAR(50)
);



INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (1,null,'t1');
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (2,1   ,'t2');
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (3,1   ,'t3');
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (4,2   ,'t4');
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (5,4   ,'t5');
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (6,null,'t6');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE  cte1 AS (
  SELECT id,parent_id,title
  FROM Categories
  where title = 't5'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte1.id,c.parent_id,c.title
  FROM cte1 INNER JOIN Categories c
  on c.id = cte1.parent_id
)
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(title separator '->') result
FROM cte1
GROUP BY id;

| id  | result         |
| --- | -------------- |
| 5   | t5->t4->t2->t1 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f9YUnKk6tBzH3LfxYuKvQi/1)

Comment: @AliMohammadi No problem

Comment: @AliMohammadi If your can't use `CTE`, you only use `while` with temp table to make it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159

Comment: oom...good query but need query without set condition of colume (`where title = 't5'`)

Comment: @AliMohammadi just use `parent_id is not null` instead of  `title = 't5'`  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f9YUnKk6tBzH3LfxYuKvQi/2

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL < v8.0 your only real choice is a stored function. I think this one will do the job for you; it emulates recursing back through the table from a child until it finds an item with no parent (`parent_id` is null):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS depth;
DELIMITER \\
CREATE FUNCTION `depth`(item VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS int(11)
   DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE d INT DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE p INT;
 SELECT COALESCE(parent_id, 0) INTO p FROM categories WHERE title = item;
 WHILE p != 0 DO
   SET d = d + 1;
   SELECT COALESCE(parent_id, 0) INTO p FROM categories WHERE id = p;
 END WHILE;
 RETURN (d);
END \\
DELIMITER ;

SELECT depth('t1'), depth('t2'), depth('t3'), depth('t4'), depth('t5'), depth('t6')
```

Output:

```
depth('t1')     depth('t2')     depth('t3')     depth('t4')     depth('t5')     depth('t6')     
1               2               2               3               4               1
```