# Ordering infinite level hierarchical result set with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

I am working on infinite level comment-reply system. And getting parent-child relative data rows successfully but I am having trouble ordering this rows.

This being used for create results: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291159/4894502

And I have results like this;

```
comment_id     comment      parent_id depth rel_path    rating
    38      Com 1               0       0      0           0
    39      Com 2               0       0      0           10
    40      Com 3               0       0      0           0
    41      Com 1-1             38      1      0/38        0
    42      Com 2-1             39      1      0/39        0
    44      Com 2-2             39      1      0/39        2
    46      Com 3-1             40      1      0/40        0
    43      Com 2-1-1           42      2      0/39/42     0
    47      Com 2-2-1           44      2      0/39/44     0
    45      Com 2-1-1-1         43      3      0/39/42/43  0
```

But ordering is problem, desired ordering is every child must be under of its parent ans children must be ordering in between according to some parameter for example `rating`. So desired result like this;

```
comment_id     comment      parent_id depth rel_path    rating
    38      Com 1               0       0      0           0
    41      Com 1-1             38      1      0/38        0
    39      Com 2               0       0      0           10
    42      Com 2-1             39      1      0/39        0
    43      Com 2-1-1           42      2      0/39/42     0
    45      Com 2-1-1-1         43      3      0/39/42/43  0
    44      Com 2-2             39      1      0/39        2
    47      Com 2-2-1           44      2      0/39/44     0
    40      Com 3               0       0      0           0
    46      Com 3-1             40      1      0/40        0
```

Or like this (+ order by rating)

```
comment_id     comment      parent_id depth rel_path    rating
    39      Com 2               0       0      0           10
    44      Com 2-2             39      1      0/39        2
    47      Com 2-2-1           44      2      0/39/44     0
    42      Com 2-1             39      1      0/39        0
    43      Com 2-1-1           42      2      0/39/42     0
    45      Com 2-1-1-1         43      3      0/39/42/43  0
    38      Com 1               0       0      0           0
    41      Com 1-1             38      1      0/38        0
    40      Com 3               0       0      0           0
    46      Com 3-1             40      1      0/40        0
```

Example on Db Fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uk3ZDLdD8N5tvhzb9S6rXC/1

Example Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `depth` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `comment` (`comment_id`, `parent_id`, `depth`, `comment`, `rating`) VALUES
(42,39, 1,'Com 2-1', 0),
(41,38, 1,'Com 1-1', 0),
(40,0, 0,'Com 3', 0),
(39,0, 0,'Com 2', 20),
(38,0, 0,'Com 1', 0),
(43,42, 2,'Com 2-1-1', 0),
(44,39, 1,'Com 2-2', 2),
(45,43, 3,'Com 2-1-1-1', 0),
(46,40, 1,'Com 3-1', 0),
(47,44, 2,'Com 2-2-1', 0);

ALTER TABLE `comment`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`);

ALTER TABLE `comment`
  MODIFY `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=48;
```

Procedure (nearly same as answer in link above):

```
delimiter #

create procedure comment_hier
(
in param_parent_id smallint unsigned
)


BEGIN

DECLARE v_done TINYINT unsigned default 0;
DECLARE v_depth SMALLINT unsigned default 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hier(
   comment_id int(11) unsigned, 
   parent_id int(11) unsigned,  
   depth int(99) unsigned default 0,
   relation_path varchar(360) default 0
)engine = memory;

INSERT INTO hier SELECT comment_id, parent_id, v_depth, 0 FROM comment a WHERE a.parent_id = param_parent_id;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp engine=memory SELECT * FROM hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from hier h inner join comment a on h.comment_id = a.parent_id and h.depth = v_depth) then

    insert into hier 
    select a.comment_id, a.parent_id, v_depth + 1, CONCAT_WS('/', relation_path, a.parent_id) from comment a 
    inner join tmp t on a.parent_id = t.comment_id and t.depth = v_depth;

    set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

    truncate table tmp;
    insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select  
    a.comment_id,
    a.comment as comment,
    a.parent_id as parent_id,
    h.depth,
    h.relation_path, 
    a.rating as rating 
from
    hier h
left join comment a on h.comment_id = a.comment_id
ORDER BY h.depth, a.comment_id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists hier;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists tmp;

END #
```

Run:

```
delimiter ;

call comment_hier(0);
```

I've been working for hours but I couldn't solve this. Thanks.

Comment: You could re-order the results in your programming language. Which one do you use?

Comment: I would seriously review whether this design is optimal

Comment: I work with php but I would like to solve this problem with mysql if possible @Adder

Comment: @Corion https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uk3ZDLdD8N5tvhzb9S6rXC/1 I added code to here. Thanks for advice. I am working on your solution.

Comment: @Strawberry Do you have advice?

Comment: My advice would be to switch to a nested set model.

Comment: @Corion root id I thought, but deeper levels cause errors, example in link Com 2-2-1 is not child of 2-1-1-1, its child of 2-2. But its position under 2-1-1-1.

Comment: @Corion still 2-2-1 wrong position

Comment: @Strawberry nested set model so complicated for this, must change so much data every new reply, isn't it?

Comment: I've fixed my query - the creation of the hierarchical path needs the root id at the front

Comment: ( https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aZJ34a8QPdZGa39G4d7BZz/12 )

Comment: @Corion thanks for your effort. I am tried code for deeper levels and alternative situation; parent child ordering seems like working thank you so much for this. But last think rating ordering not working. Here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aZJ34a8QPdZGa39G4d7BZz/9 child com 2-2 must be above com 2-1 because it has higher rating, do you have any advice for this?

Comment: It seems daunting at first, but once you get to grips with it, it's very straightforward. Read Mike Hillyer's excellent article and decide for yourself.

Comment: @Corion https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aZJ34a8QPdZGa39G4d7BZz/24 If you look here, results as I want, thank you so much for your help. Code little bit messy but I am working on it. When I was generating relation_rating_path I used multipler, I'm not sure if it's right logic but Its working, if you have better idea change as you want. If you edit the answer to give these results, I mark it as answered. Thanks again.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for info, I will look for it.

Comment: @hllktlhndd I'm not exactly sure what the logic is behind your ordering. Using a multiplier is a good idea to make all the relation path items the same width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the different orderings (by rating of the top-level comment, by hierarchy only), you will need to add all the sorting criteria to your `hier` table as new hierarchical paths. I restructured your hierarchical sort path to include both the path and the final comment id, so that each initial comment does not have `0` but `39` (or `38` or `40`) as its first component. This makes the hierarchical ordering trivial.

For ordering by rating, you have to construct each path element of `rating/comment_id`. That makes it trivial to order things by (relative rating in the thread) and then by `comment_id`.

The resulting code is

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `depth` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `comment` (`comment_id`, `parent_id`, `depth`, `comment`, `rating`) VALUES
(42,39, 1,'Com 2-1', 0),
(41,38, 1,'Com 1-1', 0),
(40,0, 0,'Com 3', 0),
(39,0, 0,'Com 2', 20),
(38,0, 0,'Com 1', 0),
(43,42, 2,'Com 2-1-1', 0),
(44,39, 1,'Com 2-2', 2),
(45,43, 3,'Com 2-1-1-1', 0),
(46,40, 1,'Com 3-1', 0),
(47,44, 2,'Com 2-2-1', 0);

ALTER TABLE `comment`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`);

ALTER TABLE `comment`
  MODIFY `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=48;

#CREATING PROCEDURE
#---------------------------------------------------------------------#
drop procedure if exists comment_hier;

delimiter $$

create procedure comment_hier
(
in param_parent_id smallint unsigned
)

BEGIN

DECLARE v_done TINYINT unsigned default 0;
DECLARE v_depth SMALLINT unsigned default 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hier(
   comment_id int(11) unsigned, 
   root_id int(11) unsigned,  
   parent_id int(11) unsigned,  
   depth int(99) unsigned default 0,
   relation_path varchar(360) default 0,
   relation_rating_path varchar(360) default 0
)engine = memory;

INSERT INTO hier SELECT comment_id, comment_id as root_id, parent_id, v_depth, comment_id, concat_ws('/',  a.rating, comment_id) FROM comment a WHERE a.parent_id = param_parent_id;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp engine=memory SELECT * FROM hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from hier h inner join comment a on h.comment_id = a.parent_id and h.depth = v_depth) then

    insert into hier 
    select a.comment_id, t.root_id, a.parent_id, v_depth + 1, CONCAT_WS('/', relation_path, a.comment_id), CONCAT_WS('/', relation_rating_path,  a.rating, a.comment_id) from comment a 
    inner join tmp t on a.parent_id = t.comment_id and t.depth = v_depth;

    set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

    truncate table tmp;
    insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

#SELECT STATEMENT
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
select  
    a.comment_id,
    a.comment as comment,
    a.parent_id as parent_id,
    h.depth,
    h.relation_path
    , h.relation_rating_path
    , a.rating as rating
    , h.root_id
from
    hier h
left join comment a on h.comment_id = a.comment_id
-- for tree-like ordering
-- order by relation_path
-- for rating ordering of the comment
order by relation_rating_path desc, comment_id
    ;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists hier;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists tmp;

END $$

delimiter ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
call comment_hier(0);

| comment_id | comment     | parent_id | rating | depth | relation_path | relation_rating_path | root_id |
| ---------- | ----------- | --------- | ------ | ----- | ------------- | -------------------- | ------- |
| 47         | Com 2-2-1   | 44        | 0      | 2     | 39/44/47      | 20/39/2/44/0/47      | 39      |
| 44         | Com 2-2     | 39        | 2      | 1     | 39/44         | 20/39/2/44           | 39      |
| 45         | Com 2-1-1-1 | 43        | 0      | 3     | 39/42/43/45   | 20/39/0/42/0/43/0/45 | 39      |
| 43         | Com 2-1-1   | 42        | 0      | 2     | 39/42/43      | 20/39/0/42/0/43      | 39      |
| 42         | Com 2-1     | 39        | 0      | 1     | 39/42         | 20/39/0/42           | 39      |
| 39         | Com 2       | 0         | 20     | 0     | 39            | 20/39                | 39      |
| 46         | Com 3-1     | 40        | 0      | 1     | 40/46         | 0/40/0/46            | 40      |
| 40         | Com 3       | 0         | 0      | 0     | 40            | 0/40                 | 40      |
| 41         | Com 1-1     | 38        | 0      | 1     | 38/41         | 0/38/0/41            | 38      |
| 38         | Com 1       | 0         | 0      | 0     | 38            | 0/38                 | 38      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aZJ34a8QPdZGa39G4d7BZz/22)